CASE WHEN query isn't working. I'm trying to add another column to SUM CV_Doggo but it's not working
I've done a CASE WHEN statement in my SQL query but it's not working for some reason.
I'm not entirely sure what I have done wrong here but it doesn't seem obvious to me.
CASE 
    WHEN (CPTY_RSK_FCTR_MTHDY_TYP <= 2000) 
        THEN '0'
    WHEN (CPTY_RSK_FCTR_MTHDY_TYP >= 2001) 
        THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
END AS CV_Doggo,
SUM(CASE 
        WHEN CPTY_RSK_FCTR_MTHDY_TYP <= 2000 THEN '0'
        WHEN CPTY_RSK_FCTR_MTHDY_TYP >= 2001 THEN '1'
        ELSE '0' 
    END) OVER (CV_Doggo) AS Total_CV_Doggo

FROM 
    ia_r_pty @ffdws1p_m.de.db.com
WHERE 
    CPTY_RSK_FCTR_MTHDY_TYP IS NOT NULL;


What does "not working" mean? You haven't shown any sample data or expected ore current results; or an error if you are getting one. But over (cv_doggo) doesn't look right - is that really over (partition by cv_doggo)? Actually... that doesn't seem to make sense at all... that's the alias for the case expression? (Also as you excluding nulls, your else can't happen; and why are you putting the 0/1 in quotes, particularly when summing?)

Your over() clause is missing the partition by keywords, and you can't refer to a column alias in the same level of subquery - so CV_Doggo isn't recognised.
You appear to want something like:
SELECT
  CV_Doggo,
  sum(CV_Doggo) over (partition by CV_Doggo) as Total_CV_Doggo
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN CPTY_RSK_FCTR_MTHDY_TYP <= 2000 THEN 0
         WHEN CPTY_RSK_FCTR_MTHDY_TYP >= 2001 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END as CV_Doggo
  FROM ia_r_pty
  WHERE CPTY_RSK_FCTR_MTHDY_TYP IS NOT NULL
);

which has the case expression to get CV_Doggo in a subquery; the alias from that is then available to the outer query.
I've removed the quotes from the 0 and 1 values as they are being treated as numbers anyway. You can also remove the first when in this instance, as the matching values will be caught by the else anyway. Or alternatively, as you're excluding nulls all values will be cause by the two when clauses (assuming that column is always an integer) so the else is redundant.
And if you wanted to see how many 0 values you get, as well as how many 1 values, then you can use count() instead of sum(). You haven't said what you want to see though...
fiddle with some made-up data and options.
